# From a question page, can I see the triage review outcome (if any)?

Tags: support, triage

I saw a poor question on the front page today.  I want to know if that question went through triage review, and if so, what the outcome of that review was.  How can I do that?

Looking at a question I triaged (so I know a triage review happened), there's no entry in the post revision history for the triage review, and I can't think of anywhere else to look.  Maybe with some manual URL editing or a SEDE query for the corresponding review?

I want this information so I can provide feedback on the triage selection heuristics ("this should have gone to triage") or on review decisions ("this doesn't Look OK!").

Comment: Using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203969/find-the-reviewtasks-for-a-post) *(maybe it needs to be updated for triage)* should bring up the reviews done for a post. Just enter the postId and run it. (Note: SEDE is only updated once a week on Sunday morning UTC, so anything after then won't be visible till it's updated next).

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other review outcome, you'll have to go looking in the [review queue history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history). Only 10k+ users can see the history of all reviews, not just their own.

Since the review history isn't exactly searchable, it's a tedious job at the best of times; you have to search using your browser page search feature and page through the review history, a manual process that is only eased by paying attention to how old the post is and where it roughly should show up in the history.

I'm not sure if users with less than 10k can see the votes of other reviewers on a post they themselves reviewed; if you have a URL to the triage queue entry you yourself reviewed I do think you can see the queue outcome (including specific user votes) once all reviews for that post are done.

Comment: Note that the recommended page has a filter to exclude any post currently on any of the review queues.

Comment: @Braiam: posts in the triage queue are not excluded from the home page, not yet.

Comment: I'm not saying that it does, but the ["Recommended tab"](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended) **has a filter** that allows you to filter them out called "Only questions not being reviewed".

Comment: @Braiam: Are you saying that that is a way to detect if a post is in the review queue?

Comment: Programmatically? Probably no. But judging from the opening sentence of OP "I saw a poor question on the front page today." it should prove useful.

Comment: @Braiam I was hoping to provide feedback on the triage selection heuristics ("this should have gone to triage") or on review decisions ("this doesn't Look OK!"), but that Recommended tab looks very useful, thanks.

Comment: You can pull these out of SEDE if you like: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/283972

Comment: @Shog9: but by the time posts end up in the SEDE dataset they are long gone from the homepage.